# Storing Random Numbers in an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am a bit confused on how I would take the randomly generated number in a range from my program, store that into an array, and read and print out from the array how many times that the number was generated.

For the random import I am using `java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom`;

```java
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    char quitOption = 'q'; 
    char continueOption = 'c';
    char input;
    int[] myArray;
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        int roll = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 6);
        System.out.println("Roll is " + roll);
        System.out.println("Enter c to continue or enter q to quit ");
        input = console.nextLine().charAt(0);

        if (input == continueOption || input == 'C') {
            roll = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 6);
            System.out.println("Roll is " + roll);
            System.out.println("Enter c to continue or enter q to quit ");
            input = console.nextLine().charAt(0);
        } else if (input == quitOption || input == 'Q') {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    } while (continueOption == 'c' || continueOption == 'C');
}
```

Comment: I'd use an `ArrayList` to store your numbers since the number of inputs is dynamic. To get the number of repeats, you can sort the list then keep checking if its neighbor is the same number

Comment: @user3170251 Actually, he should use a HashMap<int, int> and then each time he encounters a roll, he should up the value in the hashMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must figure out how to overcome two problems:

- Figure out how many rolls there will be, as `Array`'s are fixed sized
- Count how many time a number is rolled

You could use a `List`, and then use built in methods such as `Collections.frequency`, or if you are confined to an `Array`, check to make sure that adding another number will not be out of bounds, (And if it will be then copying it to a new `Array`) and then iterating over the `Array` and counting how many times each number occurs.

However, we know the range of numbers that will occur. So why not initialize an `Array` with six elements, and let `0` be `1`, `1` be `2`, and so on. Then every time that number is rolled, we increment the index of the respective number. So something like:

```
int roll = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 6);
arr[roll -1]++;
```

So if a two is rolled, we will add one to the `1th` index:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

And so on. Then when you need to count the index its a simple loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(i + 1 + " occurs: " + arr[i] + " times");
}
```

Also you are over complicating your loop. It can be simplified to:

```
char input;
int[] myArray = new int[6];
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    int roll = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 6);
    System.out.println("Roll is " + roll);
    myArray[roll -1]++;
    System.out.println("Enter c to continue or enter q to quit ");
    input = console.nextLine().charAt(0);

} while (input == 'c' || input == 'C');
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++ ) {
    System.out.println(i + 1 + " occurs: " + myArray[i] + " times");
}
```

***Sample run:***

```
Roll is 4
Enter c to continue or enter q to quit 
c
Roll is 1
Enter c to continue or enter q to quit 
c
Roll is 3
Enter c to continue or enter q to quit 
c
Roll is 3
Enter c to continue or enter q to quit 
c
Roll is 1
Enter c to continue or enter q to quit 
c
Roll is 1
Enter c to continue or enter q to quit 
q
1 occurs: 3 times
2 occurs: 0 times
3 occurs: 2 times
4 occurs: 1 times
5 occurs: 0 times
6 occurs: 0 times
```

Comment: This is actually was simpler than mine, I overthought it. HAHA

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` lets call it `rollMap`.

Each time you roll you get `int currentRoll = randomRoll()`.

If I were you, I would then say:

```
if(rollMap.containsKey(currentRoll)){
    rollMap.put(currentRoll, rollMap.get(currentRoll) + 1);
}else{
    rollMap.put(currentRoll, 1);
}
```

You can then get how many times each number was rolled by saying:

```
System.out.println(rollMap.get(<rollid>));
```